# Issue sorting a list of locations by geolocation/proximity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To solve this issue, I have been attempting to feed variables to the value attributes of an option list and sort it based on these values. Everything works great with manually assigned values, e.g.

```html
<option id="link1" value="1">A</option>
```

But I don't seem to be able to figure out how to assign each option a calculated distance to my current location and sort it accordingly.

The following code should make this issue a bit clearer:

```js
const navToSelection = _ => {
  const el = document.getElementById("panel_link_library")
  const val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].id
  window.location.href = val // That's it!
}
$("#panel_link_library").html($("#panel_link_library option").sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt($(a).val()) == parseInt($(b).val()) ? 0 : parseInt($(a).val()) < parseInt($(b).val()) ? -1 : 1;
}));

function distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1).toRad(); // Javascript functions in radians
  var dLon = (lon2 - lon1).toRad();
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

/** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}

var test_1 = window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos_1) {
  console.log(pos_1);
  console.log(
    distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 42.37, 71.03)
  );
  return pos_1
});

var test_2 = window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos_2) {
  console.log(pos_2);
  console.log(
    distance(pos_2.coords.longitude, pos_2.coords.latitude, 33.37, 71.03)
  );
  return pos_2
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent_mob">
  <div>
    <div>
      <select class="panel_link_button_2" id="panel_link_library" name="p_links">
        <option id="panel_link_library" value="">Choose a location</option>
        <option id="link1" value="test_1">A</option>
        <option id="link2" value="test_2">B</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="abc" class="panel_link_button" onclick="navToSelection()">Place a Pickup Order</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I suspect that there must be something wrong with

Comment: I fixed the syntax error. Do you mind explaining me (I am fairly new to programming) how I would be able to return two variables in this example? The console log spits out the correct 2 values on my end right now

Comment: About what variables you talk above ? `how I would be able to return two variables in this example`

Comment: var test_1 and var test_2 should both have a value assigned here, depending on where you are located, e.g. test_1=8000 and test_2=8200

Comment: Let's take test_1. The value of test_1 should translate into <option id="link1" value="8000"> which I was trying to do via <option id="link1" value="test_1">

Comment: You want to set the option test_1 value with the  variable test_1 value?

Comment: Correct!! That's exactly what I am trying to do here

Comment: Ok. But when ? At page loading

Comment: Yes, so that the user has an individually sorted list of locations based on where he is at.

Comment: If the code under the big yellow "SOLUTION" block is the answer to this questions, then you should delete that and post it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @MTK: Your whole reply vanished

Comment: Sorry some mistakes. Try It now (In your computer not here )

Comment: I posted an answer with the code I am currently using that sorts the list based on it's geo location distances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code achieves what I was trying to achieve, granted, by a work-around. Doesn't run in the snippet, but if you run it on your computer/server, it should work just fine:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  
  </script>
   
  


</head>
<body>

<div class="parent_mob">   
<div >
  <div>
    <select class="panel_link_button_2" id="panel_link_library" name="p_links">
      <option id="panel_link_library" value="0">Choose a location</option>
      <option id="link2" >B</option>
      <option id="link1" >A</option> 
       <option id="link3" >C</option> 
       <option id="link4" >D</option> 
       <option id="link5" >E</option> 
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div>
 <div id="abc" class="panel_link_button" onclick="navToSelection()">Place a Pickup Order</div>
 </div>
</div> 
  
  
  
    <script>
  
  const navToSelection = _ => {
  const el = document.getElementById("panel_link_library")
  const val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].id
  window.location.href = val // That's it!
}

</script>

<script>

function distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();  // Javascript functions in radians
  var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad(); 
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
          Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
//  console.log("navigator.geolocation d "+d);
  return d;
  
}

/** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}



 
 window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos_1) { 
   console.log("navigator.geolocation start ");
  document.getElementById('link1').value = distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 35.43,-120.34);
   console.log(pos_1.coords.longitude);
   console.log(pos_1.coords.latitude)
  document.getElementById('link2').value = distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 35.43,-119.23);
   document.getElementById('link3').value = distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 35.22,-118.32);
   document.getElementById('link4').value = distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 34.06,-118.22);
   document.getElementById('link5').value = distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 33.98,-118.44);
  
   $("#panel_link_library").html($("#panel_link_library option").sort(function (a,b) {
    
 
    return parseInt($(a).val()) == parseInt($(b).val()) ? 0 : parseInt($(a).val()) < parseInt($(b).val()) ? -1 : 1; 
  
 
}));
document.getElementById("panel_link_library").selectedIndex = "0";
});



</script>
  
  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have maded some changes to your code. I have tried it in mi PC and working good. Don't try here in snippet because don't work. Copy all code bellow paste it in a html file in your computer try it and will work.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent_mob">   
<div >
  <div>
    <select class="panel_link_button_2" id="panel_link_library" name="p_links">
        <option id="panel_link_library" value="">Choose a location</option>
        <option id="link1" value="test_1">A</option>
        <option id="link2" value="test_2">B</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div>
 <div id="abc" class="panel_link_button" onclick="navToSelection()">Place a Pickup Order</div>
 </div>
</div> 

<script>
  
  const navToSelection = _ => {
  const el = document.getElementById("panel_link_library")
  const val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].id
  window.location.href = val // That's it!
}

</script>

<script>

function distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();  // Javascript functions in radians
  var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad(); 
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
          Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

/** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}



 var test_1;
window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos_1) { 
  test_1 = distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 44.37, 71.03);
});

console.log(test_1)


 var test_2;
 
 window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos_2) {
  console.log(pos_2); 

  return distance(pos_2.coords.longitude, pos_2.coords.latitude, 30.37, 71.03)

});
console.log(test_2)




</script>

<script>
    var setted = false;
    function set_values(){
        $('#link1').val(test_1);
        if(!test_1){
    //
    }else{
     //if geolocation fail then test_1 = ''
     //then try again the geolocation
     if(test_1 == ''){
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos_1) { 
     test_1 = distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 44.37, 71.03);
    });
      //if OK stop the setTimeout
     }else{
     setted = true;
     console.log($('#link1').val());
     console.log('Te value for test_1 has been setted');
     }
    }

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!test_1 || !setted){
                console.log('The value not setted up ... I will try again in one second');
                set_values()
            }else{
                console.log('Te value for test_1 has been setted');
            }   
        },1000);
    });

</script>


<script>
  $("#panel_link_library").html($("#panel_link_library option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).val()) == parseInt($(b).val()) ? 0 : parseInt($(a).val()) < parseInt($(b).val()) ? -1 : 1;
}));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But your first question was how to add the value to option. If your variables have returned undefined ... is normal that value seem to no change ... but the solution has been `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I tried to run your code, but console.log(test_1) is shown as undefined as well. Sorry if I am not expressing myself correctly, but I thought " I am trying to feed variables to the value attributes of an option" was explaining my intent correctly. The sort function in the code above sorts a list by value. I need to assign the right coordinate distance values to each option in order to be able to sort it correctly.

Comment: The console.log within the geolocation function outputs values to the console, I thought this means that function itself works?

Comment: I updated the "Solution (in progress)" section. As you can see, it throws two errors 1. It doesn't like 'return distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 42.37, 71.03)' 2. I says Item_1 is not defined in your function

Comment: But you cannot use return inside console log().  `console.log(
  return distance(return pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 44.37, 71.03)  ); `  use `console.log(
  distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 44.37, 71.03)
  ); ` and after tat on new line   `return distance(pos_1.coords.longitude, pos_1.coords.latitude, 44.37, 71.03); `

Comment: Right, good catch. Updated the code, but it still doesn't work. See the console outputs. Does this code run correctly on your end?

Comment: (Thanks so much for helping me with this btw)

Comment: Finally I have the solution. But don't try it in the stackoverflow snippet. Read my updated answer first

Comment: I tested this code as is and also rewrote the function for link2. It doesn't work on my end. Just to confirm, does it sort your drop-down list based on distance?

Comment: It work ( as your question ) You have now the distance in the option value ... What you do with this value after that ... is another task.

Comment: Shouldn't it give me a console.log of "Te value for test_1 has been setted" if it actually assigned the value?

Comment: Yes. If you have chrome put F12 an open the devtools ... in devtools console paste `$('#link1').val()`  ... as will see the value is assigned

Comment: This show mi console: `Position {coords: Coordinates, timestamp: 1520403741059}
stack.mtk:105 The value not setted up ... I will try again in one second
stack.mtk:94 4325.19303146562
stack.mtk:95 Te value for test_1 has been setted
stack.mtk:98 4325.19303146562`

Comment: Not sure why, I copied and pasted the exact code, but on my end it gives me the following: undefined
test.html:71 undefined
test.html:104 The value not setted up ... I will try again in one second
test.html:66 Position

Comment: And if i run in devtools this : `test_1
4325.19303146562
$('#link1').val()
"4325.19303146562"`

Comment: You have a server at home ? Maybe security reasons don't allow pages from disc to geolocate

Comment: no, I just open it as a html via Chrome on my laptop.

Comment: $('#link1').val() gives me an "" output

Comment: So i have tried now like you ...(from disk) and not work (I think  secuity policy navigator) but on server localhost/stack.html working good. If you have a website ... upload them ... and you will see that work

Comment: I will upload it on the server at work tomorrow and report back

Comment: Also check if you are allowed the `localization` on your browser ... because also I have tried ant if I put them to `not allow` then also not work .... the loop stop (also form browser policy).But if I allow the localization It work (on server only)

Comment: it asks me each time and I grant permission for localization.

Comment: Ok. So tomorow You will see that work on server. But you need to manage this because users that not allow .. must be avised ...

Comment: What I am confused about is, why does it output a correct value when a console.log is added within the function, but doesn't write this value into a variable?

Comment: That because `the navigator policy stop the loop that call this`. If you change `$(document).ready(` with another event ... i.e `$('body').click(` that work (even as html page without server) I have tried now  ... in this case after open the page you must click on body to run it